# Next period lead function ssas calculation

Tags: ssas, mdx, lag, lead

I have encountered a problem with two calcultaions which I've managed to write - since I'm new to mdx ans ssas I suppose they could be written in a better way, unfortunately I do not know how to do this. My output is a table which looks as follow (picture)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngr7w.png)

Opening and closing are my calcultions, that look as below:
Opening balance:

```
(
  [Date Day].[Calendar].CurrentMember.lag(1)
, [Measures].[Closing balance in points]
)
```

Closing balance:

```
(
  [Measures].[Accrued Points]
 +[Measures].[Redeemed Points]
 +[Measures].[Opening balance in points]
)
```

Everything is working as it should - but only on small data samples, with bigger one the data is loading forever. 
I would be very grateful if you could give me some ideas on how to solve this problem

Comment: is opening balance on its own slow?

Comment: Yes it is. However, I was told today that those calulations are written as they should, so I don't relly know why they work so slowly

Comment: I'm unsure why closing balance has braces `(...)`? Braces are used to denote a tuple in `mdx` so for the closing balance measure they not required (you are using them correctly in the opening balance measure) Also am I right in thinking that both these measures seem to rely on each other? ... so does that mean there is some sort of recursion?

Comment: Ok, I'll remove those braces then. Yes, they are depending on each other, and I don't really know how to wirte it in other way (or is it even possible, as that's how they should be working)

Comment: Another thing that worries me here, is that yesterday I wrote another calcultion:      avg (nonempty
  (
   [Transaction Details].[Accrual Flag Without RV].&[1],
   [Transaction Details].[Transaction ID].[Transaction ID]
  ),
  [Measures].[Accrued points without RV]) + avg (nonempty
  (
   [Transaction details].[Redemption Flag Without RF].&[1],
   [Transaction Details].[Transaction ID].[Transaction ID]
  ),
  [Measures].[Redeemed points without RF])                          And this has been loading all night and as a result I got blanks inestad of values

Comment: I think the problem in the second one is certainly with the AVG, they were working fine on their own before, but now there's more data and they have problems with loading